# Heat of combustion per mole and per kilogram

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

I need to calculate the heat of combustion per mole and per kilogram of complete combustion of, say, X.

1. I write reaction : $\ce{X + O2 -> ... + Q}$
2. Find Q using Hess law

Now, what do I do after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q is the heat of combustion per mole. Next, you would use the formula weight to determine the heat of combustion per g (or kg).